# Как удалить репост с группы Телеграм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Подскажите, как удалить репосты с групп, очень часто, начали со своих групп, пересылать в мою группу.

Вот из документации:
switch_inline_query
По желанию. Если установлено, нажатие кнопки предложит пользователю выбрать один из своих чатов, открыть этот чат и вставить имя пользователя бота и указанный встроенный запрос в поле ввода. Может быть пустым, в этом случае будет вставлено только имя пользователя бота.

Пробовал так:

```html
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['switch_inline_query'])
async def switch_inline_query(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()
```

Проверяю в тестовой группе, код кнопки такой:

```html
switch_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Поделиться", switch_inline_query="Мой Бот.")
```

Библиотека Aiogram.

Comment: Что-то я не понял какое отношение switch_inline_query имеет к вопросу.

Comment: Вопрос решен, все работает, в тг знакомому написал.